# Nonlinear dimensionality reduction in Java/on JVM

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, java, manifold-learning

Is there a (decently) fast implementation of Manifold Learning algorithms on JVM?

I tried [Smile](https://github.com/haifengl/smile) library but it takes dozen minutes to run its Isomap on my computer, while scikit-learn implementations are couple to ten times faster.